# Base folder in directory structure

Tags: linux, macos, file, unix, directory

So I'm fairly new to UNIX (This might be basic but I couldn't find a good answer) and I'm trying to run some code I got from the web. In the README it says:

"If you put these 3rd-party packages in a `pathUtils` folder in the same base
folder as the `shadowDetection`, they should be picked up automatically by
`setPath`. "

Does this mean I need to create a `pathUtils` folder in the same directory as `shadowDetection`? So it would look like:

/path/shadowDetection

/path/pathUtils

or would it look like

/path/shadowDetection/pathUtils

Your help and understanding is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This ReadMe you're referencing (from https://github.com/jflalonde/shadowDetection) is unclear, since it's not clear whether "shadowDetection" refers to the shadowDetection *folder*, or the shadowDetection *software*. If it's the former, then your first example (pathUtils alongside shadowDetection folder) would make sense; if it's the latter, then your second example (pathUtils inside shadowDetection folder) would apply.

My guess is that the author means parallels so I'd try it your first way first, but since it's ambiguously worded, try it the other way if it doesn't work. Once you figure it out, email the author and suggest he clarify his ReadMe.